# Android studio exception during build (assembleDebug)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I have been getting a weird error in my Event log in Android studio for some time. Although my app runs as expected, this is bothering me as it 
is happening consistently.

Following is the stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.AssertionError: -2013
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.AssertionError: -2013
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap$5.onDropFromCache(PersistentHashMap.java:250)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap$5.onDropFromCache(PersistentHashMap.java:214)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.SLRUMap.clear(SLRUMap.java:145)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doClose(PersistentHashMap.java:640)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.close(PersistentHashMap.java:631)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapIndexStorage.clear(MapIndexStorage.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.MemoryIndexStorage.clear(MemoryIndexStorage.java:96)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.clear(MapReduceIndex.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.doClearIndex(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1290)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.access$2300(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl$18.run(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1236)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl$19$1.run(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:367)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:617)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.AssertionError: -2013
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.doEnumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:296)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.enumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:309)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.enumerate(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:75)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.enumerate(PersistentHashMap.java:387)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap$5.onDropFromCache(PersistentHashMap.java:231)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: -2013
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.getBufferWrapper(PagedFileStorage.java:403)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.getByteBuffer(PagedFileStorage.java:177)
    at com.intellij.util.io.AppendableStorageBackedByResizableMappedFile$3.<init>(AppendableStorageBackedByResizableMappedFile.java:160)
    at com.intellij.util.io.AppendableStorageBackedByResizableMappedFile.checkBytesAreTheSame(AppendableStorageBackedByResizableMappedFile.java:156)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.isKeyAtIndex(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:399)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.enumerateImpl(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:391)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.doEnumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:287)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Have you applied a filter to just your app?

Comment: Do you have the BashSupport plugin? They have an issue with a similar stacktrace: https://github.com/jansorg/BashSupport/issues/230

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung this stacktrace is not from logcat. It is from event logs.

Comment: @Migore yes looks like this issue was fixed in 1.5.0. I am using an older version